# Why cannot fermions have non-zero vacuum expectation value?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, fermions, symmetry-breaking, grassmann-numbers

In quantum field theory, scalar can take non-zero vacuum expectation value (vev). And this way they break symmetry of the Lagrangian. Now my question is what will happen if the fermions in the theory take non-zero vacuum expectation value? What forbids fermions to take vevs?

Answer (score 21):

Why can't fermions have a non-zero vacuum expectation value (VEV)? Lorentz invariance.

If anything other than a Lorentz scalar has a non-zero VEV, Lorentz invariance would be spontaneously broken.

For example, suppose we have a Lorentz invariant term in a Lagrangian for a vector
$$
\mathcal{L} \supset m^2 A_\mu A^\mu.
$$
Now suppose the vector obtains a VEV, $A_\mu \to v + A_\mu$,
$$
 m^2 A_\mu A^\mu \to m^2 v A^\mu + m^2 vA_\mu + m^2v^2 + m^2 A_\mu A^\mu.
$$
The first two are clearly not Lorentz invariant. One can construct idential arguments for any non-scalar field term. If $\psi\to v+\psi$, the VEV, $v$, won't have the same Lorentz transformation properties as the field, $\psi$ unless $\psi$ is a scalar.

Comment: Hi @innisfree, thanks for your answer. But, it will be very helpful, if you could explain it a bit more mathematically?

Comment: Take the fermion field to have spin 1/2. A spin 1/2 defines a direction in space, the direction such that the spin 1/2 is "up" with respect to that direction. If this field interacts with other fields, this breaks rotational symmetry. The only spin that does not define a preferred direction in this way is spin 0, that is, a scalar.

Comment: @Paul, is it clearer now?

Comment: Having said that, I suppose there could be very special theories, in which e.g. vectors appeared always as $\partial_\mu A^\mu$, allowing a VEV.

Comment: @innisfree: I don't think this has to do with Lorentz invariance, but that's it is a general fact about Grassmanian fields, though I don't know the proof...

Comment: @innisfree: In any "derivatively-coupled" theory, one cannot have a vev, right? Since there is no special point in field space.

Comment: @Paul: VEV = Vacuum expectation value i.e. a property of the vacuum. So if any object in a non-trivial representation of the Poincare algebra picks up a VEV, then some of the spacetime symmetries will be _spontaneously broken_ by the vacuum (state). One can expect the same to apply to fluctuations around the vacuum. That would mean that the corresponding conserved quantities are not really conserved. And as far as we can see, conservation of energy-momentum and angular momentum apply quite perfectly to our universe.

Comment: @siva good point.

Comment: @innisfree

Shouldn't we take $\langle\Omega|A_{\mu}|\Omega\rangle=v_{\mu}$? It can not be just $v$. The Lagrangian obviously cannot contain a term like $m^2 vA_{\mu}$, it is a four-vector. However, if you consider $v_{\mu}$, the expression you wrote can be written in a Lorentz-invariant way and no problem would arise. My question is more general. What is the VEV of a spin-$s$ (integer or half-integer) field in a general quantum field theory? To which extent one can answer this question?

Comment: I guess my notation isn't great. Yes, the Loretnz index of A is contracted with an index on $v$, so maybe I should write $v_\mu$ but the point is that $v$ doesn't transform like a $v_\mu$.

Comment: just as $<h> = (0, v)$ doesn't transform like an SU(2) doublet

Answer (score 13):

I think it is a general fact about grassmannian field, and this has nothing to do with Lorentz invariance or other symmetries (you can invent a lot of QFTs without this kind of symmetry, but the VEV of a fermionic operator will be always zero (in the absence of sources)).

In a functional integral formulation, the VEV of a grassmannian field $\psi$ is written as $$ \langle \psi \rangle= \int D\psi D\bar\psi\, \psi \,e^{-S},$$
where the action S is bosonic (involves products even products of $\psi$ and $\bar\psi$). Therefore, unless there are source terms of the form $\bar\eta\psi$ in the action, the integral over the $\psi e^{-S}$ will give zero, since we are integrating over an odd number of grassmannian fields (when the exponential is expanded).

Comment: Can't one make similar arguments for a scalar vev $<\phi>=0$? It ought to be zero, which is why we expand about the homogeneous nonzero part in Higgs mechanisn

Comment: Any field linear in creation and annihilation operators will give a zero vev

Comment: @innisfree: Not necessarily. If the action is not symmetric (say to $\phi\to-\phi$, where $\phi$ is bosonic), then you can have $\langle\phi\rangle\neq 0$. For creation operator, this is not the case, if you include a source $J$, compute $\langle\hat a^\dagger\rangle$ at finite source, and the let $J\to0$ (and if there is a degeneracy between two states with a difference of one particle). For fermions, you will always find that as $\eta\to0$, then $\langle\psi\rangle\to0$.

Comment: @Adam I think your argument is incorrect. Think of the bosonic example that innisfree has mentioned with the $Z_2$ symmetry $\phi\rightarrow-\phi$, with your argument you would conclude that $\langle\phi\rangle=0$ which is wrong as spontaneous symmetry breaking of $Z_2$ may in fact happen.  Your error  is simply setting the sources J for the fermion to zero, but when there is spontaneous symm breaking the result depends on the way you take the limit as the action is non-analytic in J. Moreover, in my answer I have provided an explicit weakly coupled example that does break Lorentz

Comment: @TwoBs: SSB won't change anything, since already for explicit symmetry breaking (for a condensate $\bar\psi\psi$) won't give you a finite $\langle\psi\rangle$, because Grassman variables are completely different from bosonic variables. Stated in a different way: I challenge you to find a reference talking about $\langle\psi\rangle\neq 0$ (without linear sources).

Comment: @Adam  I have run your very same argument for the bosonic $Z_2$ example, where it fails. Do you agree on this? If so, why should I believe in your argument for the fermionic example? Besides, I have already provided a weakly coupled example where $\langle\psi\rangle$ arise with no source. Not to mention the continuum limit of a lattice with the spin locked to each side, that provide a model for spontaneous symmetry breaking of rotations where a finite magnetization is induced even without sources.

Comment: @TwoBs: of course your argument works for bosons, never said otherwise. Your "example" is not one, since you haven't done any calculation showing it works. Because it won't. And your example with magnetization doesn't work either, since spins are quadratic in fermionic operators... which of course can have a finite vev.

Comment: @adam I'm quite interested in this. If you have time, maybe you could settle the matter by extending your answer with the technical details about the differences between scalar and fermion VEVs, and why twobs potential won't break Lorentz

Comment: @innisfree: put it that way: a fermionic annihilation operator $\hat c$ is a standard QM operator. Therefore, the average of $\hat c$ with respect to any physical state should give a complex number. Thus having $\langle \hat c\rangle =\psi$ with $\psi$ a grassmann number is impossible. It is in fact trivial to check that $\langle \hat c\rangle=0$ for any physical state (that is, $a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle$ with $a,b$ complex number. Stated otherwise, fermionic coherent state are not physical states, just very useful to write down a path integral.

Comment: @Adam I agree that I haven't done the calculation for the example, I will try to be more explicit as soon as I get some spare time in the next few days. I also agree that the spin operators are actually bosonic, sorry for the confusion. But I insist that $\langle\psi\rangle$ can be non-zero (allowing breaking of Lorentz). For example, should somebody hand you the following non-analytic piece of functional generator $\delta Z(\eta,\bar{\eta})=\sqrt{\bar{\eta}\eta}$ that is meant to produce SSB, wouldn't you agree on a $\langle\psi\rangle\neq0$? (the $\eta$ and $\bar{\eta}$ are the sources)

Comment: @Adam let me add a comment on your reply to innisfree.  I think that your argument there, which I think is correct, doesn't imply though a vanishing Vev, but rather that fermions and their grassmann vevs aren't physical observable. I would agree with that, but not on the vanishing of the fermionic   Vevs. That doesn't mean they have no effect (think again to the Higgs boson which is charged under a gauge symmetry, which isn't physical,  and yet its 'breaking'  by the Higgs vev has physical consquencies)

Comment: @TwoBs: in fact, I'm not that happy with my argument, since one can find a density matrix that allows a non vanishing expectation value. But of course, it won't be a grassmann number, whereas a mean-field approximation of the action would generate that.  But I think that your $\delta Z$ is not possible, because when you expand the exponential of the sources, there is only one term, $\bar\eta \psi$, so there is no way to generate a square root (which would do the job, indeed).

Comment: @Adam ok, I think I am convinced that you are right (but maybe with tiny loophole at the end). I just realized that one can actually never build non-analytic functions of grassmann constant variables fourth power would vanish. They are bound to be finite polynomial of order 4, hence analytic, which rules out the spontaneous breaking. The (maybe) loophole, I think, would be departing from constant sources and  vevs, that is breaks also translations. In this way I think expect one should be able to build non- analytic function(al)s of the sources and thus construct a fermionic vev. Thanks Adam!

Comment: @TwoBs: no problem, it was useful to me too, and forced to organize my thoughts ! Though I don't think having non constant sources would change anything. The partition function will be analytical in all the $\eta(x)$ by the same argument I think.

Answer (score 2):

Can't we just evaluate the partition function and then find the expectation value?
$Z=\int \mathcal{D}\phi \mathcal{D}\phi ^* \exp \left [  \int \left ( -\phi^*  G^{-1}\phi +\phi  j^*+j \phi ^* \right ) \right ]=\det\left(G^{\mp 1}\right) \exp \left ( \int j^* G j \right )$,

where $\mp$ corresponds to bosons and fermions respectively. Summing over the Matsubara frequencies of $j^* G j$,

$\sum _{\omega } j^*(\omega ,k) G(\omega ,k)  j(\omega ,k)
=\frac{1}{(2 \pi )^3} \sum _{\omega } \frac{j(\omega ,k) j^*(\omega ,k)}{\frac{k^2}{2 m}-\mu -i \omega }
= \pm j^*(k) \frac{1}{(2 \pi )^3} \left(\frac{1}{\exp \left(\beta  \left(\frac{k^2}{2 m}-\mu \right)\right)\mp 1}\pm \frac{1}{2}\right) j(k)$.

$\Rightarrow \langle \phi(k) \rangle= \pm \left[\frac{\delta \log Z}{\delta j^*(k)}\right]_{j^*,j=0}
= \left[ \frac{1}{(2 \pi )^3} \left(\frac{1}{\exp \left(\beta  \left(\frac{k^2}{2 m}-\mu \right)\right)\mp 1}\pm \frac{1}{2}\right) j(k)\right]_{j^*,j=0}$.

The Bose function has singularity at $\frac{k^2}{2m}=\mu$, and we encounter $\frac{0}{0}$. The Fermi function has no singuarity, and we get the expectation value strictly zero.