# "Constant Fermion"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, supersymmetry, fermions, symmetry-breaking

I was talking to a professor in my institution which works in Lorentz Violation of various QF theories.

While we talk about a SUSY lagrangian, I asked him if we could have a fermion acquiring VEV and break the Lorentz invariance of the theory.

He told me that, it implies a CONSTANT FERMION and it does not make sense. And I'm wondering now, does it or does it  not?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108112/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic, well they say that it breaks L invariance, but I'm asking, if I want to see some violation in this symmetry CAUSED by something like that, why it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I never heard "*constant fermion*" before. I guess you would have to ask *him* what he means...