# Why can only the Higgs particle have a non-zero expected value in a vacuum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

What does the phrase “Due to Lorentz invariance, only the Higgs particle can have a non-zero expected value in a vacuum” mean?

Comment: We need some context here. Any scalar field can have a vacuum expectation value. So what does "only" mean? Was there a list?

Comment: @mikestone I assume OP refers to the fact that the Higgs field is the only scalar field in the standard model, so if we accept that only scalars can have a nonzero VEV then the Higgs is the only SM field that can have nonzero VEV.

Comment: I agree, see e.g. this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/108114/226902

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the Higgs *field*, not the Higgs *particle*, that has a nonzero vacuum expectation value (VEV).

The Higgs field is a *scalar* field. Scalar fields don’t have a direction in spacetime; they just have a value. Other fields such as spinor fields (for electrons, quarks, and neutrinos) and vector fields (for photons, gluons, and weak bosons) do have a direction in spacetime. (In the case of spinors, I’m simplifying a bit.) Lorentz transformations change this direction, so a VEV for spinor and vector fields could not be Lorentz-invariant; for the scalar Higgs it can.

Comment: Nince answer. Can you please tell me where the graviton would fall into, which group? Vector field and thus that one can't have nonzero VEV either?

Comment: Gravitons are represented by a tensor field with two indices. As with a vector field with one index, a nonzero VEV for such a field would not be Lorentz-invariant.